# jQuery adding two totals together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic form where customers can select a range of tickets via Checkboxes and Select Boxes. Then it generates a sub total.

I am just looking to how I can add these two sub totals together.

My HTML is

```
    <form id="calx-south-green">
            <fieldset id="adults">
                <legend>Additional Adults - <span class="red">£228</span></legend>
                <div>
                    <label for="1">1</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="228" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="2">2</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="228" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="3">3</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="228" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="4">4</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="228" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="5">5</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="5" value="228" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select name="proc" id="proc">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="Adult Sub Total" id="adults_total" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="young">
                <legend>Young Adults 16-21 - <span class="red">£146</span></legend>
                <div>
                    <label for="1">1</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="146" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="2">2</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="146" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="3">3</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="146" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="4">4</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="146" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select>
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="Young Sub Total" id="young_total" />
            </fieldset>
            <div>
                <label for="base_fee">Base Fee</label>
                <input type="text" name="base_fee" id="base_fee" value="228" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="result">RESULT HERE</p>
            </div>
</form>
```

My Code is:

```
    var total_adults = $("#adults_total");
var checkBox_adults = $("#adults input[type='checkbox']");
var _select_adults = $("#adults select");

checkBox_adults.click(function(){
    checkBox_adults.prop("checked", false);
    var _index = $(this).attr("id");

    total_adults.val(_index * 228);

    _select_adults.val(_index);

    checkBox_adults.each(function(){
        if (_index > 0) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            _index--;
        }
    });
});

_select_adults.change(function() {

    checkBox_adults.prop("checked", false);

    var _val = $(this).val();

    total_adults.val(_val * 228);

    checkBox_adults.each(function() {
        if (_val > 0) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            _val--;
        }
    });

});




var total_young = $("#young input[name='Young Sub Total']");
var checkBox_young = $("#young input[type='checkbox']");
var _select_young = $("#young select");

checkBox_young.click(function(){
    checkBox_young.prop("checked", false);
    var _index = $(this).attr("id")
    total_young.val(_index * 146);
    _select_young.val(_index);
    checkBox_young.each(function(){
        if (_index > 0) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            _index--;
        }
    });
});

_select_young.change(function() {
    checkBox_young.prop("checked", false);
    var _val = $(this).val();
    total_young.val(_val * 146);
    checkBox_young.each(function() {
        if (_val > 0) {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            _val--;
        }
    });
});
```

For adding in jQuery I tried doing this but its not working

```
var num1 = $("#adults_total").val(),
    num2 = $("#young_total").val(),
    result = parseInt(num1, 10) + parseInt(num2, 10);
$(".result").text(result);
```

I also have a fiddle demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/L2as6143/1/

Comment: you need to add the result calculation in with the change events. At the moment it just runs on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as

```
    var total_adults = $("#adults_total");
    var checkBox_adults = $("#adults input[type='checkbox']");
    var _select_adults = $("#adults select");

    checkBox_adults.click(function(){
        checkBox_adults.prop("checked", false);
        var _index = $(this).attr("id");

        total_adults.val(_index * 228);

        _select_adults.val(_index);

        checkBox_adults.each(function(){
            if (_index > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _index--;
            }
        });
    });

    _select_adults.change(function() {

        checkBox_adults.prop("checked", false);

        var _val = $(this).val();

        total_adults.val(_val * 228);

        checkBox_adults.each(function() {
            if (_val > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _val--;
            }
        });

    });




    var total_young = $("#young input[name='Young Sub Total']");
    var checkBox_young = $("#young input[type='checkbox']");
    var _select_young = $("#young select");

    checkBox_young.click(function(){
        checkBox_young.prop("checked", false);
        var _index = $(this).attr("id")
        total_young.val(_index * 146);
        _select_young.val(_index);
        checkBox_young.each(function(){
            if (_index > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _index--;
            }
        });
         Total();
    });

    _select_young.change(function() {
        checkBox_young.prop("checked", false);
        var _val = $(this).val();
        total_young.val(_val * 146);
        checkBox_young.each(function() {
            if (_val > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _val--;
            }
        });
        Total();
    });

        function Total(){
var num1 = $("#adults_total").val(),
        num2 = $("#young_total").val(),
        result = parseInt(num1, 10) + parseInt(num2, 10);
    $(".result").text(result);
       }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2as6143/2/)

Previously missed function calling on first check box changes.

[**UPDATED ANSWEER**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2as6143/3/)

Comment: you missed the **minus functionality** in you code - it means when user unchecked  the  value it should minus from the grand total- which is not happened in your code.

Comment: you should called your function **`Total();`** into `dropdown_changed` event also.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there a way of still calculating the total even if they only use one of the categories? At the min I just get a Nan until I use the second category.

Comment: Sorted it by adding a value="0" to the totals

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `$("#adults :checked").length + $("#young :checked").length`. This counts and adds the number of checked checkboxes in each fieldset.

Comment: They need the total value of the checked boxes, not the count

Answer (score 0):

Try this - >

```js
    var total_adults = $("#adults_total");
    var checkBox_adults = $("#adults input[type='checkbox']");
    var _select_adults = $("#adults select");

    checkBox_adults.click(function(){
        checkBox_adults.prop("checked", false);
        var _index = $(this).attr("id");

        total_adults.val(_index * 228);

        _select_adults.val(_index);

        checkBox_adults.each(function(){
            if (_index > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _index--;
            }
        });
    });

    _select_adults.change(function() {

        checkBox_adults.prop("checked", false);

        var _val = $(this).val();

        total_adults.val(_val * 228);

        checkBox_adults.each(function() {
            if (_val > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _val--;
            }
        });

    });




    var total_young = $("#young input[name='Young Sub Total']");
    var checkBox_young = $("#young input[type='checkbox']");
    var _select_young = $("#young select");

    checkBox_young.click(function(){
        checkBox_young.prop("checked", false);
        var _index = $(this).attr("id")
        total_young.val(_index * 146);
        _select_young.val(_index);
        checkBox_young.each(function(){
            if (_index > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _index--;
            }
        });
    });

    _select_young.change(function() {
        checkBox_young.prop("checked", false);
        var _val = $(this).val();
        total_young.val(_val * 146);
        checkBox_young.each(function() {
            if (_val > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _val--;
            }
        });
    });


$('input[type="checkbox"], select').click(function() {
         
         var num1 = $("#adults_total").val();         
         var num2 = $("#young_total").val();
         console.log(num1 + "   " + num2);
         var result = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
         $(".result").text(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calx-south-green">
                <fieldset id="adults">
                    <legend>Additional Adults - <span class="red">£228</span></legend>
                    <div>
                        <label for="1">1</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="228" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="2">2</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="228" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="3">3</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="228" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="4">4</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="228" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="5">5</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="5" value="228" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select name="proc" id="proc">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="Adult Sub Total" id="adults_total" />
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="young">
                    <legend>Young Adults 16-21 - <span class="red">£146</span></legend>
                    <div>
                        <label for="1">1</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="146" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="2">2</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="146" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="3">3</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="146" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="4">4</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="146" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select>
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="Young Sub Total" id="young_total" />
                </fieldset>
                <div>
                    <label for="base_fee">Base Fee</label>
                    <input type="text" name="base_fee" id="base_fee" value="228" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="result">RESULT HERE</p>
                </div>
    </form>
```